# Enable Remote Desktop Connection on SBS 2011 without need for VPN

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, remote-desktop-services

I would like to be able to establish a connection from my home PC to my work PC through a Windows Remote Desktop Connection. The server is running on Windows Small Business Server 2011.

A VPN has been set up for me, which allows the RDP to work. However, the company only has three VPN licences at present and thus this represents a limitation.

What would need to be done to allow an RDP connection without VPN? The remote web portal has an SSL certificate.

The previous company I worked for had it set up so that users could log in to `https://remote.<<COMPANYNAME>>.domain` and see their computer listed, click connect and it would download a .rdp file for them to then log into with their network username and password. I'd like to achieve this.

Comment: They were probably using some form of RD-gateway, e.g. [RDS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-plan-access-from-anywhere). If you don't use this, VPN is a sensible solution. There are VPN options without the need for licensing (OpenVPN, some IPSec implementations) and Microsoft itself offers a VPN/remote solution, e.g. [Microsoft Always On VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/vpn/always-on-vpn/always-on-vpn-technology-overview) (which needs some licensing again).

Comment: `The previous company I worked for had it set up so that users could log in to https://remote.<<COMPANYNAME>>.domain and see their computer listed, click connect and it would download a .rdp file for them to then log into with their network username and password. I'd like to achieve this.` - Have you asked the person(s) who manage the server to set this up for you? It's fairly simple to set  up in SBS.

Comment: Ah and: SBS 2011 (or its components) will be EOL soon, better upgrade sooner than later.

Comment: @Lenniey I think RDS sounds about right - so RDS as secure as RDP+VPN, whilst RDP on its own is not recommended for security reasons? Does RDS still allow the remote control of a computer (my office computer) which is connected to the network?

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the Remote Web Access website which is a component of SBS 2011. You indicate that it may be set up already, but if you are hesitant there are guides online as to how to set it up and configure it as part of Remote Desktop Services.

See:
[YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSs_eMElhiQ) 
[Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Server-Essentials-and/Introduction-to-SBS-2011-Standard-Remote-Web-Access-RWA/ba-p/397960) 
[Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2472211/how-to-manage-the-remote-desktop-gateway-service-in-sbs-2011-standard)

As you mention, you will need a server certificate that is trusted by the remote client.

It would be worth thinking very hard how to secure this server from malicious attacks if it is going to be open to web requests from the world.